# How to check file similarity case in-sensitively

Tags: bash, shell, file, unix, case-insensitive

The idea is to tell whether two given files have the exact same content, but regardless of case differences.

e.g. If file1 were `alpha` and file2 were `AlphA`, then Script file1 file2 gives 'Same'.

How to make the Script case in-sensitive?

```
#!/bin/bash
if cmp $1 $2 >/dev/null  ; then
   echo "Mostly the same."
else
   echo "Different."
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cmp` uses byte-by-byte comparison, so you'll have to do your own case conversion first:

```
if cmp -s <(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <"$1") <(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <"$2"); then
  echo "Mostly the same."
else
  echo "Different."
fi
```

- `-s` makes `cmp` silent - i.e., if there are differences, they are not printed.
- `<(...)` is a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) that, loosely speaking, makes a command's output appear as a temporary, effectively self-deleting file; since process substitutions use pipes, using them is memory-efficient and works even 
  with large output sets.
- `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` performs a locale-aware conversion of the characters provided via stdin from uppercase to lowercase, resulting in all-lowercase output.
- Also note how `$1` and `$2` are *double-quoted* to ensure that their values are used *as-is* (double-quoting protects the values from [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
file1=$(cat $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
file2=$(cat $2 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

if [ "$file1" = "$file2" ]; then
    echo "same"
else
    echo "different"
fi
```

Comment: This works (leaving the lack of double-quoting and the useless use of `cat` aside), but reading entire files into memory is best avoided, if more memory-efficient solutions are available.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are small enough, you can do it more simply.

```
#!/bin/bash
f1="$(<"$1")"
f2="$(<"$2")"
if
  [[ "${f1^^}" = "${f2^^}" ]]
then
  echo "Mostly the same."
else
 echo "Different."
fi
```

Comment: ++, but it's worth noting that the `^^` parameter expansion (which converts the entire variable value to uppercase) requires Bash v4+ (won't work on macOS).